# Perl Seeing if an object is a member of a particular class

Tags: perl, oop

Look at the following example program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;


my $new_foo = Foo->new();
my $new_foo_bar = Foo::Bar->new();

say '$new_foo is an object type ' . ref $new_foo;
say '$new_foo_bar is an object type ' . ref $new_foo_bar;


package Foo;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

package Foo::Bar;
use base qw(Foo);
```

This returns:

```
$new_foo is an object type Foo
$new_foo_bar is an object type Foo::Bar
```

Is there a way to test whether `$new_foo_bar` is also an object type of `Foo`? I know it is. I could take advantage of my naming convention and simply assume that anything that has a reference type that matches `/^Foo(::)/ is that object type, but that is only true if I follow that convention. Is there an official Perl way of determining if an object is of that object type?

Something like this:

```
if ( is_a_memeber_of( $my_object_ref, "Foo" ) {
    say qq(\$my_object_ref is a member of "Foo" even though it might also be a sub-class of "Foo");
}
else {
    say qq(\$my_object_ref isn't a member of "Foo");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[isa](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#The-UNIVERSAL-Class).

```
if ($new_foo_bar->isa('Foo')) {
    say "Yep, it's a Foo";
} else {
    say "What happened?";
}
```

Comment: Wow, that Universal class is full of neat stuff. I can use the `can` method to see if my class can do a method before attempting it. Before, I was wrapping it in an `eval` and checking my eval.

Comment: @DavidW. note that if you are doing this as validation, isa is also a class method, so `"Foo"->isa('Foo')` is true (which you may or may not want).  Also, a reference that is not an object will throw an exception if you try to call a method on it.  Because of these things, it's common to say `if (blessed $new_foo_bar && $new_foo_bar->isa("Foo"))` (where blessed is from Scalar::Util)

Comment: @DavidW.: that is `can`, not `does`.  does is more like isa, only intended for more complex OO systems with roles.  If you have to work on older systems, be aware that DOES is fairly new (5.10).

Comment: @ysth You're right about that. I had it in my script as `can` and just tested it. I've corrected my comment above.

Comment: @ysth I was always wondering what `blessed` was for in `Scalar::Util` since it seemed that `ref` did pretty much the same thing: Returns the name of the class if the object was blessed.

Comment: ref also returns the type of non-blessed (non-object) references

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23340/discussion-between-david-w-and-ysth)

Answer (score 3):

Every Perl class inherits from the built-in `UNIVERSAL` class, which contains a method called `isa`, which checks to see if an object inherits from a given class.

So you can write

```
say '$new_foo_bar is an object type Foo' if $new_foo_bar->isa('Foo')
```